# create DOM elements by a limited interval with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create 1 div container every `x` second. And I want to do this `n` times.

So I started creating this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    createEle(i);
  }
});

function createEle(value) {
  var d = $("<div></div>");
  d.addClass("d");
  d.html(value);
  $("#container").append(d);
}
```

```css
.d {
  height: 20px;
  color: white;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

</div>
```

this works fine. But I want to integrate the time interval.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      createEle(i);
    }, i * 1000);
  }
});

function createEle(value) {
  var d = $("<div></div>");
  d.addClass("d");
  d.html(value);
  $("#container").append(d);
}
```

```css
.d {
  height: 20px;
  color: white;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

</div>
```

As you can see in the second example, I always get the wrong value because it passes in the wrong index value.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `var` with `let`.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      createEle(i);
    }, i * 1000);
  }
});

function createEle(value) {
  var d = $("<div></div>");
  d.addClass("d");
  d.html(value);
  $("#container").append(d);
}
```

```css
.d {
  height: 20px;
  color: white;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

</div>
```

**Reason**

`var` doesn't let go of the **bindings of the parent lexical-environment** hence its hoisted value is retained in the asynchronous callback handler (of `setTimeout`), however `let` doesn't hold on to the bindings of any lexical-environment other than its own current one.

Comment: let is not working properly in IE

Comment: why replace var with let? i want to know, really

Comment: @plonknimbuzz I have given the reason in the answer itself.

Comment: This is amaze! +1

Comment: thanks mate. i will dig this with google

Comment: @gurvinder372: if i use `const` and `let`, i will no need to use `var` anymore. because `var` is unclearable /ambiguous. is this true?

Comment: @plonknimbuzz Both have their own uses as they do different things. Also `var` has **function scope** while `let` has **block scope**.

Answer (score 1):

please update your code. no need of for loop.

```
var i=1;
$(document).ready(function() {

  setInterval(function() {
      createEle(i);
    }, i * 1000);
});

function createEle(value) {
  var d = $("<div></div>");
  d.addClass("d");
  d.html(value);
  $("#container").append(d);
  i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop will completely executed before the first [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) runs. So the value of the i will be 5

Treat `setTimeout` and `setInterval` as a asynchronous function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 0;
  var tmer = setInterval(function() {
    createEle(i);
    i = i + 1;
    if(i==5)
      clearInterval(tmer);
  }, 1000);

});

function createEle(value) {
  var d = $("<div></div>");
  d.addClass("d");
  d.html(value);
  $("#container").append(d);
}
```

```css
.d {
  height: 20px;
  color: white;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

</div>
```